# Using glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER) would not draw anything

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm running the following code to draw rectangles using `GL_GREATER` function,
but instead of getting the color of the farthest rectangle from the camera, I get a white screen.

```
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -0.5);
glRectf(-1, -1, 1, 1);
glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(0, 0, 1);
glRectf(-1, -1, 1, 1);
glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
glPopMatrix();
glRectf(-1, -1, 1, 1);
```

So I'm expecting to see the farthest rectangle color on  the screen, which is green (which is also weird because the zNear is -1 and using `GL_LESS` draws green instead of red - I don't understand why aswell).
however using `GL_GREATER` I get a white screen instead of green.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the values in the depth buffer are in range [0, 1]. See [`glDepthRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml).
When the depth buffer is cleared, then the depth values are set to 1 by default. See [`glClearDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearDepth.xhtml).

If every value in the depth buffer is 1 and the depth test is `GL_GREATER`, then the depth test will fail in any case, because no depth can be grater than 1.
The value which is used to clear the depth buffer can be changed by [`glClearDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearDepth.xhtml).

Set the clear value for the depth buffer to 0, instead of 1, before the buffer is cleared:

```
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); 
glClearDepth(0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are flipping the comparison, you also have to flip the depth buffer clear value with `glClearDepth`. Set it to 0.